# Couldn't find Teamplayer without an ID

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Not sure why but i get this error: `Couldn't find Teamplayer without an ID`

It happens on this line:

```
<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.find(@ids), "id", "playerid") %>
```

I have this in my Teamplayer controller:

```
def index
  @teamplayers = Teamplayer.all
  @ids = params[:ids]
end
```

The value that is supposed to come from the jquery

```
var ids = 1
$.post("http://localhost:3000/teamplayers/", { ids:ids}, function(data) {
    alert('test 3');
    });
```

I ran firebug on the jquery and the variable ids is being set but i think somehow that it is not getting through to the controller. Why is that? I want to accomplish posting that variable back to the same page but in the select_tag that posted above.

Comment: I suspect that params[:ids] is nil which would cause the error that you're seeing. What is the value of params when this post happens? Should be able to see it in your console

Comment: in firebug this is what the post looks like with the ids variable translated: `$.post("http://localhost:3000/teamplayers/", { 1:1}, function(data){ alert('test 3');

Comment: and yes the params[:ids] is nil, but why is the variable going to the controller where I am trying to set it to an instance variable

Answer (score 0):

Change the content in your `select_tag` to

```
<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.all, "id", "playerid") %>
```

You are listing all the Team players in the drop-down,so `Teamplayer.all` would do the Trick.

Comment: that does work but i have a value of 1 set in the  that has the exact id value for the items i want because I only want ids for people that belong to team 1